# Angular: Dynamically changing image (portrait/landscape) using media queries?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, sass, media-queries

I am trying to change an image depending if a device is either portrait or landscape. Doing this normally I would use media queries but the 2 images I need to replace are dynamic and stored in a config file.

I was wondering if its possible, with Angular, to plug into the media queries and change the image dynamically depending on the orientation?

I am also using SASS but I still don't see a way to do this via code.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you should be using the picture element:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture

Checkout picturefill if you're supporting older browsers:

https://github.com/scottjehl/picturefill

Comment: Thats pretty cool :-) I was wondering also if you are aware of any media query service for angular. $mdMedia exists in Angular Material Design but I don't want to add it all into my site just to use, what seems a really good angular service.

Comment: Also the polyfil for the picturefill seems really cool but I am a littel concerned about the problems regarding android 2.3 / safari browsers. Fixing one appears to cause a problem in another

Comment: Have you tried just inserting the $mdMedia factory into your project? https://github.com/angular/material/blob/v1.0.9/src/core/util/media.js

Comment: Looking at the factory, you would also need to include $mdConstant.